# Cannot invoke "org.keycloak.common.util.KeycloakUriBuilder.clone()" return value of "org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getAuthUrl()" is null

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, docker, keycloak

i just started working with keycloak docker with spring boot, i'm trying to create an authentification server using keycloak and spring security , i created a docker comopse file with the keycloak image and connect it with posgresql database , then added the right propreties to my app, it was working i get to log in and the keycloak generate a token so there was no problem , then after i checked again i get a 500 server error
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.keycloak.common.util.KeycloakUriBuilder.clone()" because the return value of "org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getAuthUrl()" is null**

this is the docker compose file :

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak_local
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloak
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak_local
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

and this is the app properties:

```
server.port = 8090
keycloak.realm=lbv-realm
keycloak.resource=auth-client
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=none
keycloak.public-client=true
```

this is the keycloak configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
```

and this is the login function :

```
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> login(LoginRequest loginrequest) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("client_id",client_id );
        map.add("client_secret", client_secret);
        map.add("grant_type", grant_type);
        map.add("username", loginrequest.getUsername());
        map.add("password", loginrequest.getPassword());
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map,headers);
        ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/lbv/protocol/openid-connect/token", httpEntity, LoginResponse.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and the controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> login (@RequestBody LoginRequest loginrequest) {
        return loginservice.login(loginrequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of Keycloak adapters [was deprecated](https://www.keycloak.org/2022/02/adapter-deprecation) more than a year ago.

I've successfully moved to Spring Cloud OAuth2 Login module, check these resources:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/index.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect